# Firebase Web read requests are blocked during the Google crawl - webmaster tools

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've made a fun site using firebase web sdk. I secured the read requests with anonymous login. And added the site domain as allowed host. So site can query firebase db but direct requests to the firebase db are blocked. So all good here. However, when I try to fetch & render my site through Google webmaster tools, the dynamic part generated with firebase data is not rendered at all. Moreover, in the resources part it says firebase request is "not authorized."

[image]

Btw, I don't block anything in robots.txt.

Is there a workaround for that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not certain, but any data you want readable by a crawler must be publicly readable (not even guarded by anonymous auth). I'd try enabling read globally and see if the crawler is able to fetch.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBleigh for the answer. However, it defeats the purpose of having a secure datastore if anybody can read it. Finding the db path is as easy as checking out the js file of my site. And then they can download everything i have in my db; even they can create the same site by using the same db.

Comment: Anything readable by anonymous auth can be downloaded just as easily (well, marginally more difficult but not much). I would recommend setting granular `read: true` rules *only* for the specific paths you listen to on publicly accessible endpoints. Then a root download won't work but you'll still have SEO advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody else also faces this, here is my workaround:

- Sadly there is no direct workaround for this
- You need to make the nodes of the root publicly readable but not the root node itself in the firebase rules. To do that I used this type of rule:

  "root": {
      "$id": {
          ".read": true,
          ".indexOn": ["title"],
      }
  }
- $id refers to the the key of the elements under that root. eg:

  "root": {
      "123": {
          "title": "hola"
      },
      "124": {
          "title": "hola2"
      },
  }

So in this case, `root.json` will receive a "permission denied" from firebase. However, `root/123.json` will receive the proper json.